# Create an application that loads a website?

Tags: android, ios, asp.net-mvc

I have an existing MVC web application and I want to create a native application for Android, IOS, and PC that, when launched, navigates to a website but does not show typical browser features such as the URL bar, navigation buttons, bookmarks, etc.

Are there any tools that will allow me to do this for one or more of the targeted platforms?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use UIWebView for native Android and iOS.

To target cross platform, [Apache Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) ( use to be [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/)) is worth looking in to, but the experience (already not ideal with a webView) will be worst than if you manually create native apps for each platform.

Comment: Can Cordova / PhoneGap be used on existing applications? I was under the belief that they were intended to be used from the beginning of principle development.

Comment: They're just a glorified wrapper for a website that can handle system specific features, like notifications or orientation changes for example. You can use them with existing websites. However, if your website doesn't meet Apple standards, it will likely not pass their review.

Comment: With regard to the comment edits, you are saying that the experience of manually writing to a UIWebView is superior to using Cordova?

Comment: No, a full native app will have a better experience than using a WebView or Cordova. I would recommend using a WebView if you're only displaying an existing website. Since you mentioned cross-platform, I mentioned Cordova, which probably isn't the best choice for displaying an existing website.

Answer (score 1):

I can't really speak to the merits of cross-platform development tools.

For an iOS native solution a UIWebView will do exactly what you want.